# What is the order order-only prerequisites are processed in a GNU Make file?

Tags: gnu-make

I've been reading the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) but it's still unclear to me how the order is processed.  In the example:

```
myrule: | myrule_step1 myrule_step2
    @echo "$(@)"

myrule_step1:
    @echo "$(@)"

myrule_step2:
    @echo "$(@)"
```

what will print first?  `myrule_step1` or `myrule_step2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is *unspecified* and can run in either order. This isn't just a theoretical concern. It can happen during parallel builds. Assuming the same Makefile as in the question, I ran:

```
watch -n 0.1 make -j8
```

It only took a few seconds to print:

```
myrule_step2
myrule_step1
myrule
```

See also [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647612/2137996) by Jörg W Mittag:

> No, the order is not defined. That is the whole *point* in using declarative dependency-oriented programming: that the computer can pick the optimal evaluation order, or in fact, evaluate them even *at the same time*.

However, as mosvy points out, this is only true for GNU Make. POSIX make (which can be emulated in GNU Make by adding the special `.POSIX` target to your makefile) specifies a left-to-right ordering when handling prerequisites.

Comment: Is this really the case, or is it simply because the `echo`s are run as external commands via fork+exec, and it's up to the kernel the order in which to schedule them to run? Does it also happens if you replace the `@echo "$(@)"` with `@: $(info $@)`?

Comment: @mosvy - There's no difference. If make guaranteed that they ran left to right, it would have to wait for one to finish before starting the next to make parallel builds behave the same as serial ones. But then you wouldn't actually get any parallelism.

Comment: The bottom line is that if you need something to depend on something else, then you _declare it as a dependency_. Use `myrule_step2: | myrule_step1` to get the desired ordering in OP's question.

Comment: Do you mean you can get it to do the `$(info $@)` functions in reverse order? My impression (maybe false) was that GNU make doesn't parallelize *itself*, but the external commands it runs (the `echo`s or the `:`s in the examples)

Comment: @mosvy - It's not about the parallelism, it's about what `make` guarantees and why. Even if GNU make _happens_ to process dependencies left to right doesn't mean it _has_ to. Because it doesn't promise that it does, you can't rely on it. Why doesn't it make that promise? Because there wouldn't be a way to reconcile it with parallel builds that touch the filesystem.

Comment: 1. You brought up the parallelism red-herring, which doesn't prove anything. 2. A `make` program is required by the standard to process prerequisites left to right, and you answer doesn't really convince that GNU make changed that for its "order-only" prerequisites extensions (look at the [susv4 spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html), especially the `y.tab.o` example from the rationale).

Comment: 3. I don't see why GNU make cannot reconcile a hard left-to-right or righ-to-left order in which to process its prerequisites with running all the commands in parallel.

Comment: re 3: because if you introduce dependencies in LTR and BTF order, then you have fully expressed the order of all targets. No two can be reordered, therefore none can run in parallel. re 2: nowhere in the GNU make documentation does it say that any prerequisites are processed left to right. The susv4 spec speaks only of "most historical implementations", and that extensions should be used to get different behavior.

Comment: @mosvy - GNU make diverges _substantially_ from POSIX make and in fact contains a POSIX mode (`.POSIX` akin to `.PHONY`) in order to bridge compatibility differences.

Comment: Indeed at the very beginning of the document you post, it specifies "To receive exactly the behavior described in this section, the user shall ensure that a portable makefile shall: (*) Include the special target .POSIX". I don't know why you think this documentation overrides GNU Make's own documentation as it pertains to GNU Make.

Comment: Sorry, I won't bother you further, but that makes no sense. GNU make can guarantee the order in which it processes its prerequisites, and let it to the OS to determine in which order the commands are actually run. You're like "a shell cannot guarantee that the output of `a` will go to the input of `b` in a `a|b` pipeline and still run `a` and `b` in parallel", which is ridiculous.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93388/discussion-between-alex-reinking-and-mosvy).

Answer (score 2):

Order-only prerequisites is not about the order in which they are processed. They can be processed in any order, and can be processed even in parallel. Order-only means that updating prerequisite doesn't make updating the target. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58040049/5447906).

Answer (score 1):

While it's not clear from the documentation, running the example you will find that the order is indeed from left to right.

```
myrule_step1
myrule_step2
myrule
```

Comment: If it's not in the documentation, is it really guaranteed to run left to right, or is that an implementation detail that might change in a newer version?

Comment: With `-j` option they will run in parallel.